# SMTP Relay is unable to send mails to inside domain

Tags: windows, server, smtp, relay

Emails are triggered from our HP Process Automation 7.5. The SMTP server configured in the application as localhost.
We have SMTP Relay configured under Windows Server 2012 R2 under IIS. Mails triggered by the application is able to send mails to outside domains. We are using domain as [mycompanyname.in]. The mails sent to inside our domain is not delivering.
ie, the SMTP relay server is able to send the mails to email ids such as user3465@gmail.com, but it is not able to deliver the message to email ids such as user3465@mycompanyname.in.

Any issue with .com & .in domains in SMTP relay server?

My Server is MS Server 2012 R2 patched uptodate.

Please help us resolve the issue.